# Exception on splitting a String with delemeter "##&&**&&##"

Tags: android, string

I am having a problem in splitting a string on basis of following delemeter:

```
    ##&&**&&##
```

This is how I am trying to split the string:

```
    String[] errorDetails = errors.split("##&&**&&##");
```

But I get following exception:

```
    regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 6:##&&**&&##
```

Here index 6 is being pointed as the first "&" after "**".

I tried to use toString() method as well but it is still giving me the same problem. Can anyone give me any idea how to get rid of it. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character * has special meaning in regular expression. You need to escape it to remove the special meaning.

```
String[] errorDetails = errors.split("##&&\\*\\*&&##");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "`##&&**&&##`" is taken as a regular expression, but it is not considered to have a valid syntax. How about using a regular expression in a correct syntax that exactly represents "`##&&**&&##`" as written below?

```
.split("[#]{2}[&]{2}[*]{2}[&]{2}[#]{2}");
```

Hope that's help

Comment: Thats also a good idea. +1 from me. I'll try to use it in future.Thanx dude!

Answer (score 0):

try the following one:

```
   String[] errorsdetails = errors.split("@#$");
```

Comment: brother, I am getting this string from server. So it already consists this expression in it. I can't change it.